# Vue how to pass child and parent component data to method

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I make form with `v-for` syntax. I successfully get percent data from child component when I write only method name.

**Parent component**

```
<div v-for="(item, idx) in recipients"
     :key="idx">
  <range-input @sendValue="getPercentFromChild">
  </range-input>
</div>

...

getPercentFromChild(percent) {
    console.log(percent); // 50
  },
```

**Child component**

```
<div>
  <input type="range"
         value="0"
         @change="sendValue">
</div>

...

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    sendValue() {
      this.$emit('sendValue', 50);
    },
  }
}
```

Then, How can I pass **child data(percent) and parent data(indx)** to methods?

Like this, **Parent component**

```
<div v-for="(item, idx) in recipients"
     :key="idx">
  <range-input :currentPercent="0"
               @sendValue="getPercentFromChild(idx, percent)">
  </range-input>
</div>

...

getPercentFromChild(idx, percent) {
   console.log(idx, percent); // 0, undefined
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch the emitted value with `$event` parameter, while calling the callback for `sendValue` event.

**Parent Componet:**

```
<div v-for="(item, idx) in recipients"
     :key="idx">
  <range-input :currentPercent="0"
               @sendValue="getPercentFromChild(idx, $event)">
  </range-input>
</div>

...

getPercentFromChild(idx, percent) {
   console.log(idx, percent); // 0, 50
},
```

here is a demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/476282/)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the emit twice but pass in different parameters. Might sound odd but it works. Try this:

```
 <div v-for="(item, idx) in recipients"
     :key="idx">
  <range-input @sendValue="getPercentFromChild" v-on:sendValue="getIndex(idx)">
  </range-input>
</div>
```

then you can have two methods and use them to perhaps set data elements that you use in a third method:

```
data: () => ({
        index: 0,
        percentFromChild: 0,
    }),
methods: {
    getPercentFromChild(percent) {
      this.percentFromChild = percent
    },
    getIndex(i) {
      this.index = i
      this.thirdFunction(this.percentFromChild, this.index)
    },
    thirdFunction(a, b) {
      //do stuff
    }
```